# Does manipulating credit card numbers in javascript cause a security issue?

Tags: javascript, security

I'm working on a credit card processing web application. The application uses HTTPS (TLS). However, the entry page (jsp) copies the credit card information from the original form to another hidden form using javascript. Does this represent any security issue above using a single form? Can a hacker alter javascript to steal data on an HTTPS connection? We do have a site certificate.

Comment: Where is the hidden form?

Comment: It's no less secure than it would be without manipulating the information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the security of credit-card processing, rather than how to programmatically implement/improve credit-card handling via code. Possibly a fit for [security.se].

Comment: the hidden form must also be transmitted via https

Comment: Whenever you run code that is processing foreign data (e.g. user input) you might open an attack vector. So you always need to know what kind of attacks are possible and if your code might be prone to such attacks.

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, if a "hacker" had access to the javascript on the page they could find out the details whether you had manipulated them with javascript or not, in the same way you are.

Comment: I guess I just don't know what is possible in terms of attacks that could alter web page/javascript content. But I guess if you can do that, you could get any data you wanted from the page, regardless.

Comment: Modifying the DOM with input received by the user or another foreign source, can create a possibility to inject script.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying page objects within the DOM is protected by [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in the browser. If you are manipulating it within the same domain only, it does not add additional risk. It would only become a problem if you were using JavaScript to send card data to domains outside of your control.

> the same-origin policy is an important concept in the web application security model. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port number[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) – to access each other's DOM with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to DOM on different sites